# Creating references instead of copies of objects for arrays

Tags: objective-c

Let us say that there are 5 song objects, namely `Song *song1, *song2, *song3, *song4, *song5`

Now there are totally three classes, `Song, Playlist, MasterCollection`

As the names indicate, the `Song` classes can be used to create a new song, print the song etc.

The `Playlist` class can create new playlists and add songs to it or remove songs to it.

The MasterCollection contains a list of playlists and a method which can be used to create a library of all the songs.

My question is, I want to define my methods such a way that when a Song is removed from library of the masterCollection, it should be removed from the playlists too.

So i did something like this.

I defined a new object of MusicCollection class called mainCollection and added songs to it.

```
[MainCollection.library addObject: song1];
[MainCollection.library addObject: song2];
[MainCollection.library addObject: song3];
[MainCollection.library addObject: song4];
[MainCollection.library addObject: song5];
```

The I created a playlist using the Playlist class

```
[playlist1 addsong:mainCollection.library[0]];
[playlist1 addsong:mainCollection.library[3]];
[playlist1 addsong:mainCollection.library[2]];`
```

The idea is to update the playlist1 when say song1 is removed from the mainCollection.

```
[mainCollection.librray removeObject: song1];
```

but the playlist1 is not getting updated. It still shows that there are 3 songs.

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: What is going on with all the spelling error? 'mainColeection', 'librray'. Check if your problem lies there.

Comment: I just typed it out in the StackOverflow editor. I didn't copy paste any code.

Comment: There's no magic. You put an object in two collections. Removing from one will in no way remove it from another automatically. You wrote code to add it to the two collections so you need to write code to remove it from both collections.

Comment: @maddy I understand that I am creating an explicit reference as I can see that the object is not getting removed. I wanted to know how to implement the removing method.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this

```
[playlist1 addsong:mainCollection.library[0]];
```

Objective-C takes the element of the `mainCollection.library` array at index zero, and adds a reference to it into the `playlist1` array. At this point, `song1` object has two collections referencing it - the `mainCollection.library` and `playlist1`. The two collections are independent of each other, so you cannot manipulate one of them to change the content of the other one.

There are several ways to deal with this.

The most common way is to delete all references to the song being deleted: it is not overly expensive, and it is very easy to implement.

Another common way is to set up a collection that connects songs to playlists - say, an `NSMutableDictionary` with `Song`s as keys (you need to implement hash code and equality methods) and `NSMutableArray` of `Playlist`s as elements. This collection creates a maintenance headache, but it lets you avoid searching playlists that do not contain the song.

Finally, you can use the "tombstone" pattern. Instead of storing songs in the master list and in playlists, store a special `SongReference` object. In addition to a reference to `Song`, the `SongReference` can have an `isDeleted` flag. Instead of removing songs from lots of collections, you would simply mark the `SongReference` deleted. Unfortunately, the rest of your code would have a task to pay attention to whether the song is deleted or not.

Comment: @Morpheus It looks like the task is asking for the master list to manage playlists as well. This would mean that in addition to `addSong:` and `removeSong:` methods it would have methods such as `addPlaylist:`, `removePlaylist:`, `addSong:toPlaylist:`, `removeSong:fromPlaylist:` and so on. This way the master list would be able to clean up both the master list itself and the playlists that contain the deleted `Song` object.

Comment: I didn't lit all my methods. The problems says that use references instead of copies. So I am stumped at how to use the references.

Comment: @Morpheus Your code already uses references - in Objective-C, everything that you declare with an asterisk (roughly speaking) is a reference. If you want to make a copy, you need to implement a method `copy`, and call it on the object. Otherwise, all collections to which you add a `Song` will be referencing the same `Song` object. For example, if you change the name of the song in the master list, the name of songs in all playlists will change automatically.